# why the static initialization block not executing while accessing inherited static variable in below code?

Tags: java

```
class Parent
{
    static int y = 4;
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    static
    {
        System.out.print("static Initialization block ");
        y=9;
    }
    static void fun()
    {
        System.out.print(y);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.print(Child.y); // line L1
        Child.fun(); // line L2
    }
}
```

Line 1 outputs: 4

Line 2 Outputs: static Initialization block 9

Now, my Doubts are:

1. I have read that whenever we initialize a class, static initialization block executed first then why line L1 not executing the static initialization block, while line L2 executes the static initialization block ?
2. Does the static variable y of parent class inherited to child class or not?

Comment: `Child.y` is interpreted as `Parent.y` in this case, because `y` is actually on `Parent`. Decompile your class file with `javap -v` to verify this. That's actually why `Child.y` is an antipattern: you should always access static fields with the "correct" class.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler turns `Child.y` into `Parent.y`